# How does C access files?

Tags: c

everyone! I'm learning how to access files in C but, I wonder how my program(or C) access files(drive sectors)? I'm searching the Internet for answers but they don't have some proper explanation on how C(or my program), loads drive sectors to memory. Please give me some clarity, and thanks in advance.

Comment: What level of "how" are you asking about?

Comment: Down at the hardware level it depends on the manufacturer and type of drive (SCSI is different to IDE to Winchester to USB, ...). That's part of the reason having an Operating System is a good idea. The developers of the Operating System talked to the manufacturers of the disks (or read the documentation) and made it easier to access the disk through the OS. Same as C: the developers of C made it easy to access the disk through the OS (and through the hardware).

Comment: Like low-level.

Comment: low level IDE, low level USB, low level SCSI, ...?

Comment: So like the compiler or header looks what function is suitable to the platform?

Comment: Most C implementations call operating system routines. Going much beyond that is a very broad subject, as there are many issues to cover, involving different operating systems, different file systems, a variety of hardware that can be accessed in various ways, and more. You would really need to narrow the question down to specific situations.

Comment: There are many levels, and each of them can be relatively "low". You could pick a specific C file-handling function and ask what exactly is happening in it under the hood. Still, will be pretty broad, but way narrower than it is currently.

Comment: It asks the operating system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C programs use functions of the kernel or a device driver to access hardware. A computing platform (Windows, Linux, OSX, etc) that supports C provides an implementation of the [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) for programmers. This library contains system specific implementations of functions for accessing files, like `fopen`. The systems implementation of the standard library is most often just a wrapper around their specific system calls. For example on Windows, the C standard library is going to end up calling these functions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/